# trivially-copy-assignable vs trivially-copyable

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following code. It can be compiled with both Clang and GCC. However, GCC issues a warning:

> warning: 'void* memcpy(void*, const void*, size_t)' writing to an object of non-trivially copyable type 'struct Value'; use copy-assignment or copy-initialization instead [-Wclass-memaccess]

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

static unsigned cnt2 = 0;

struct Value {
  Value(int v) noexcept : v(v), m(v+1) { }
 ~Value()      noexcept { cnt2++; }
  int v; 
  int m; 
};

static_assert(std::is_trivially_copy_assignable_v<Value>);

void copy(Value* dst, Value const* src, std::size_t len) {
  std::memcpy(dst,src,sizeof(Value)*len); }

int main() { std::cout << "Hello\n"; }
```

There are at least two problems here.

1. Both compilers pass `std::is_trivially_copy_assignable_v<Value>`. So what is the difference between *trivially copy assignable* and *trivially copyable* types?
2. I think the warning is correct. Because destructor of `Value` is non-trivial. So does this mean that to use `std::memcpy` we have to check both `std::is_trivially_copy_assignable_v<Value>` and `std::is_trivially_destructible_v<Value>`?

Answer (score 1):

> Both compilers pass `std::is_trivially_copy_assignable_v<Value>`. So what is the difference between *trivially copy assignable* and *trivially copyable* types?

**Trivially-copy-assignable** requires just operations involving copy-assignment to be trivial. You can have a trivially-copy-assignable class with, for example, a non-trivial destructor or move constructor. Such a class **won't be trivially-copyable**.

> I think the warning is correct. Because destructor of `Value` is non-trivial. So does this mean that to use `std::memcpy` we have to check both `std::is_trivially_copy_assignable_v<Value>` and `std::is_trivially_destructible_v<Value>`?

I believe you only need to check `std::is_trivially_copyable_v<Value>`. Both your checks don't give you the required guarantee, since your class can still can have, for example, a non-trivial move constructor and, therefore, will not be trivially-copyable, and, therefore, will not be usable with `memcpy`.

Comment: I've seen that using memcpy when type isn't trivially copyable is UB. But why did they add is_trivially_x traits in C++17 if it is not to use memcpy in specific cases ?

Comment: @ThiSpawn I don't think these traits were added in C++17. They were added in C++11. One motivation for adding them might be to make _type traits_ "complete" in this regard. Why not adding them? You never know where they may be useful.

Comment: @ThiSpawn One example — consider you have dynamically allocated arrays of objects of some type. If this type is _trivially-destrutible_, you can skip _deleting_ these arrays and consequently make program exiting faster. Trivially-destructible objects do not need to be destructed (destruction is no-op) and memory will be released by the system when the process is finished automatically.

Comment: Ok for trivially desctrutible since it is defined that "trivial" means no-op in this case. However let's say I have 2 initialized trivially-copy-assignable objects. Then I can't use memcpy to assign one to the other.. because the meaning of "trivial" in this case is compiler-specific! Only trivially-copyable ensures memcpy is enough. That's why I don't really know why is_trivially_copy_assignable_v<..> exists if it only indicates "it is trivial for the compiler; whatever it means".